# Handling Hyperlinks in WPF RichTextBox Html?

Tags: c#, html, wpf, xaml, hyperlink

I have a `RichTextBox` in a WPF application (C#.NET4.5). The `RichTextBox` is in Rtf format. I'm using a [MarkupConverter](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e) to convert and save the `RichTextBox.Text` Rtf text back in the Db as Html. If a user opens an existing record, the markup converter converts from Html back into Rtf for display in the UI. All works well.

I have an issue trying to handle Hyperlinks. Because the Markup Converter has to convert from Rtf-Xaml-Html I don't believe that there is a Xaml tag which equates to `Href` or `HYPERLINK` as there is in Html or Rtf?

Therefore the converter is just stripping out the hyperlink.

Is there any way to handle this in Xaml?

Thanks

Comment: There is a way to [handle hyper links in XAML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink.aspx) and HTML to XAML converter does it for sure (I am using that and you can search for `AddHyperlink` in the HtmlToXamlConverter.cs). I don't know about RTF to HTML conversion but I assume links are lost in there. Did you try to save HTML and see what's in there?

Comment: Yeah just noticed that the Xaml string has: </Run></Span><Hyperlink Foreground="#FF6D6D6D" NavigateUri="http://www.w3schools.com" TextDecorations="Underline"><Span TextDecorations="Underline"><Run>Visit W3Schools</Run></Span></Hyperlink> so just trying to build that into the HtmlFromXaml switch statement but I'll take a look at AddHyperLink.

Comment: Yeah at the moment, the MarkupConverter just deletes the whole hyperlink & associated tags. You're right, the MarkupConverter handles Html tags to Xaml but not the other way round. That's exactly what is happening in my app. So I'll try to reverse the `AddHyperlink` logic in Xaml to Html...

Comment: Struggling with this as the HTML - Xaml method isn't easy to reverse...

Comment: Note to self, ensure you've downloaded the latest Source code... Thanks @dkozl

Comment: where can i download the latest source code ??

Comment: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Converting-between-RTF-and-aaa02a6e, you might have to tinker with the souce code to get the HTML output to your liking.