# Hyperlink while converting XAML to HTML

Tags: wpf, xaml

The hyperlink in XAML is truncated while converting it to HTML.

```
<FlowDocument>"<Hyperlink Foreground=\"#FF6D6D6D\" NavigateUri=\"http://domain.com.au?tag=ThisIsListTag&amp;somequery=Test\" TextDecorations=\"Underline\">Click here</Hyperlink>"</FlowDocument>
```

using the Demo code in MSDN (https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/XAML-to-HTML-Conversion-ed25a674/view/SourceCode), it truncates the above Hyperlink..

has anyone solved this issue?

Someone actually raised the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390464/handling-hyperlinks-in-wpf-richtextbox-html)..  but i cannot find the answer to this..

Comment: If you have found a bug in the GitHub project you should raise this as an issue on the GitHub project: https://github.com/mmanela/MarkupConverter/issues

Comment: the code github project is copied and paste from the MSDN..   https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/XAML-to-HTML-Conversion-ed25a674/view/SourceCode